# Problem with wireless connection in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, bluetooth

Ever since I upgraded my OS to `Bionic Beaver`, my wireless connections(both  WiFi and bluetooth) are not working properly. Most of the time, they don't get connected to a network/device. Even when they do, the connection is intermittent. I have had this problem for a while now and and posted in several forums but in vain.

In addition, whenever I say `Install now` to a software update prompt, I get the following error message, even though my wired connection is working perfectly fine over the browser.

[image]

I use a HP15-bs179tx laptop.

Some more information can be [found here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4xytdBP3p6/)

Comment: `echo options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf` Reboot, check BIOS settings, restore factory Secure Boot keys but leave Secure Boot set to disabled

Comment: @Jeremy31: Can you please tell me how to restore factory secure boot keys?

Comment: It might be in BIOS/system config/boot options, Load HP factory keys

Comment: @Jeremy31: Do you mean that I should factory restore my computer? Can you please elaborate?  I don't know what factory keys are. And googling it didn't help either.

Comment: Loading the HP factory keys in BIOS is not restoring your entire computer, just the factory Secure Boot keys, dkms doesn't work well without them

Comment: @ Jeremy31: I do see options to 'Load HP factory secure boot keys'. But they are greyed out. How do I enable them?

Comment: Try to enable Secure Boot, then see if the keys can be loaded, then disable Secure Boot again

Comment: @Jeremy31: I have loaded the HP factory secure boots key(I had to disable to 'Legacy Mode' to do that.) but it didn't help. My WiFi is not even detecting any network now. What can I do now?

Comment: You may have to uninstall rtlwifi new and reinstall using dkms, but what does `mokutil --sb-state` show now?

Comment: @Jeremy31 It shows `SecureBoot disabled` . Can you please tell me how do I uninstall rtlwifi or link me?

Comment: @Jeremy31: Uninstalling and reinstalling rtlwifi did not help. :(

Comment: What results for `dkms status; modinfo rtl8723de`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Here is the result : https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ZMRGMy9ryT/